# node.js how to delay importing modules

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am new to google-map. I want to create a map where, when user click on any location. it will allow user to place marker on map.

I try to use map.addEventListener("click"), which works fine. 
mycode:

```
function initMap() {    
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12
  });


  map.addListener('click', function clickHandler() {
    //do something
  });
}
```

However when user click on any landmark/clickableIcon https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7PxJ.jpg,.

Google-map will show infobox and ignoring the clickHandler, https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCtkm.jpg. it seems that each of the landmark/clickableIcon has event.stopPropagation();

Is there any way to enable both methods. That is when user click on clickableIcon, it will both show infoBox and place the marker on the map.

thanks,

Comment: Does this have anything to do with its title?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
placeMarker(event.latLng);
});

function placeMarker(location) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
});
}
```